# Convenient way to add a structure to a list of structures

Tags: vb.net, list, structure

I have defined a structure like this:

```
Private Structure udtString2
    Dim String1 As String
    Dim String2 As String
End Structure
```

Now I want to fill a list of udtString2 with values, and I would like to do it in a convinient, well structured and easy to read way.

I would like to ask if it is possible to do something like this?

```
Dim n As New List(Of udtString2)

'Pseudocode

n.Add(udtString2("TextA1", "TextA2"))
n.Add(udtString2("TextB1", "TextB2"))
```

Or if there's any other to do it as nicely visible like this.

Comment: Tangential to the question, I'd be very cautious about using a struct instead of a class because the value semantics can cause surprising behavior.  It gets even harder to wrap your head around when the members of the struct are reference types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a constructor for your structure:

```
Private Structure udtString2
    Dim String1 As String
    Dim String2 As String

    Public Sub New (s1 as String, s2 As String)
        String1 = s1
        String2 = s2
    End Sub
End Structure
```

Then you can use it almost how you want:

```
n.Add(new udtString2("TextA1", "TextA2"))
n.Add(new udtString2("TextB1", "TextB2"))
```

Comment: And add a constructor with no parameters if you want to keep using it as before.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
n.Add(New udtString2() With { .String1 = "TextA1", .String2 = "TextB1" })
...
...
...
```

Also, you could use a collection initializer to make it more compact rather than calling `n.Add` subsequently.